# How to get path to the root node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is the first time I am playing with neo4j and I would be grateful if you could look at my cypher script. I have simple tree of `MyNode` which are connected to each other with nodeId.

**NodeEntity:**

```
@NodeEntity
public class MyNode {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private Long nodeId;
    private int amount;

    @Relationship(type="BELONGS_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private MyNode parent;

}
```

Now I would like to get **all nodes up to the root node and make the sum of the `amount` field of these nodes**. If I have this tree:

```
100<-102<-103
100<-101
```

The query:

```
MATCH (p:MyNode)-[:BELONGS_TO*]->(c:MyNode) WHERE c.nodeId = 103 RETURN p.nodeId
```

returns the empty set (awaiting 102, 100), however

```
MATCH (p:MyNode)-[:BELONGS_TO*]->(c:MyNode) WHERE c.nodeId = 100 RETURN p.nodeId
```

returns 101, 102, 103, so it works in the opposite direction (lists all children of the node and not the path up, towards the root node).

Answer (score 0):

Your Tree seems to be a directed tree.

```
100<-102<-103
100<-101
```

when you use the query

```
MATCH (p:MyNode)-[:BELONGS_TO*]->(c:MyNode) WHERE c.nodeId = 100 RETURN p.nodeId
```

this works since the relationship arrow is pointing towards the root node.

> 103-[:BELONGS_TO]->102-[:BELONGS_TO]->100

However when you use the following query

```
MATCH (p:MyNode)-[:BELONGS_TO*]->(c:MyNode) WHERE c.nodeId = 103 RETURN p.nodeId
```

it is searching for

> (:MyNode)-[:BELONGS_TO*]->103

however in your example the arrow is pointing away from the 103.

**So the solution is to point the arrow in the other direction.**

```
MATCH (p:MyNode)<-[:BELONGS_TO*]-(c:MyNode) WHERE c.nodeId = 103 RETURN p.nodeId
```

which should work.

Hope this helps.